# Functions returning more functions creating endless loop

Tags: lua, infinite-loop

Hey guys I just started learning Lua and I accidentally made an infinite loop that I don't really understand so I was wondering if you guys can explain what happened here thanks. :D

```
function test(x) 
print (x)
return test(x) + test(x)
end
```

Then when test(2) is entered it loops 2 infinitely till it stops.
Any explaination is appreciated thanks. :D

Comment: When asking a question, it's helpful to explain the behavior you expected to see (in addition to what you did see). That way, we can more directly address your misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

It's called recursion. Your function is calling itself before returning. Most languages will have issues like stack overflows after a certain depth in the recursion is reached. So it's most likely not actually infinite.

The second test call (`+ test(x)`) will never actually be reached. But since test() would never actually return anything but `nil` no matter what value you pass, it would actually crash because calculating `nil+nil` is illegal in Lua.

Comment: Since we have no idea what the function would return if it was fixed, the second paragraph is irrelevant. It can't return anything as written.

Comment: It is a deep philosophical question: what is the datatype of return value of a Lua function which never returns?  :-)